# How do I update an XML attribute from an MSBuild script?

Tags: xml, msbuild, msbuildcommunitytasks

I am using [MSBuild](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0k6kkbsd.aspx) and [MSBuild Community Tasks](http://msbuildtasks.tigris.org/) (using XMLUpdate and [XMLMassUpdate](http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/dorony/archive/2008/01/18/easy-configuration-deployment-with-msbuild-and-the-xmlmassupdate-task.aspx)) to update various sections of my Web.config one thing has me stumped though. If I have:

```
<configuration>
    <nlog throwExceptions="true" xmlns="http://www.nlog-project.org/schemas/NLog.xsd" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
       <targets>
            <target name="file" xsi:type="File" fileName="${logDirectory}\SomeLog.log" layout="${message}"/>
        </targets>
    </nlog> 
</configuration>
```

and I try to replace the `fileName` of the `target`

```
<XmlUpdate XmlFileName="$(BuildDir)\Builds\%(Configuration.Identity)\_PublishedWebsites\Presentation\Web.config"
           XPath="//configuration/nlog/targets/target[@fileName]"
           Value="${logDirectory}\SomeLog_%(Configuration.Identity).log" />
```

It reports as being unable to find anything to update, so my question is how can I get the filename attribute to updated?

---

**EDIT:** Could this be a case of namespace clashes as the NLog section defines its own namespace?

---

**UPDATE**: The posted answer declaring the name space does not work.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The first problem is the xpath is incorrect for updating the attribute, it is currently looking for "target" nodes with an attribute called "fileName" rather than the "fileName" attribute of the a node called "target".

The xpath you want is:
/configuration/nlog/targets/target/@fileName

As for the namespace issue, [Preet Sangha has the correct answer for that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1271840/how-do-i-update-xml-attribute-with-msbuild/1271868#1271868), you need to use the namespace prefix, and this must be applied to every sub-element as well, since they are all in that namespace.

The final statement being:

```
<XmlUpdate
  Prefix="n"
  Namespace="http://www.nlog-project.org/schemas/NLog.xsd"
  XmlFileName="output.xml"
  XPath="//configuration/n:nlog/n:targets/n:target/@fileName"
  Value="${logDirectory}\UpdateWorked.log" />
```

Answer (score 4):

[Here](https://web.archive.org/web/20200928212440/http://geekswithblogs.net/paulwhitblog/archive/2006/04/11/74844.aspx) it indicates the requirement of a namespace

```
<XmlUpdate
   Namespace="http://schemas.microsoft.com/.NetConfiguration/v2.0"
   XmlFileName ....
```

can you update any other attribute?

Comment: This is helpful but doesn't solve the problem at hand I have other XMLUpdate tasks that don't declare the namespace but update correctly

Answer (score 3):

To complete the answer given by [keeperofthesoul](https://stackoverflow.com/users/35233/keeperofthesoul) *(I think you should give him the bounty btw)* take a look at:

```
<XmlUpdate
  XmlFileName="web.config"
  XPath="//configuration/x:nlog/x:targets/x:target/@fileName"
  Value="%24{logDirectory}\SomeLog_%(Configuration.Identity).log"
  Prefix="x"
  Namespace="http://www.nlog-project.org/schemas/NLog.xsd"
  />
```

Here I'm using `%24` to write out the special character `$`.