# Update Xml File (vsixmanifest)

Tags: xpath, msbuild, teamcity, vsix, vsixmanifest

I'm creating a Visual Studio 2013 Package (vsix) (shameless plug: [pMixins](http://www.pmixins.com) ).  As part of my quest to use [TeamCity](http://www.jetbrains.com/teamcity/) as a continuous integration server, I have configured Team City to build the .vsix Package ([Visual Studio Package (vsix) - Team City without Visual Studio installed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24161827/visual-studio-package-vsix-team-city-without-visual-studio-installed)).

Now I want to configure Team City to set the Version in the VSIX [Schema](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh696828.aspx):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<PackageManifest 
    Version="2.0.0" 
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/vsx-schema/2011" 
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/vsx-schema-design/2011">
    <Metadata>
        <Identity  Version="1.0" Language="en-US" Publisher="Company" />
```

Following the advice in [Using msbuild I want to update a config file with values from teamcity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8658972/using-msbuild-i-want-to-update-a-config-file-with-values-from-teamcity) and [How do I update an XML attribute from an MSBuild script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1271840/how-do-i-update-an-xml-attribute-from-an-msbuild-script) I have updated `Microsoft.VsSDK.targets` to use [XmlPoke](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff598687.aspx) with the following Target:

```
<Target 
     Name="UpdateVSIXVersion" 
     BeforeTargets="PrepareForBuild" 
     Condition="$(VSIXVersion) != '' And $(VSIXVersion) != '*Undefined*'">

    <Message Text= "Updating VSIX Version" />

    <XmlPoke 
        XmlInputPath="source.extension.vsixmanifest"
        Query="/PackageManifest/Metadata/Identity/@Version"
        Value="$(VSIXVersion)">         
    </XmlPoke>      
 </Target>
```

I updated Team City with a system Parameter to set `VSIXVersion`:

[image: Screen shot of Team City System Parameters]

But, when I check TeamCity, it made 0 replacements:

[image: Team City Build Log]

**How do I get Team City to correctly update the .vsixmanifest xml?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After much searching I finally found the XmlPoke expects a `namespace` when the Xml file contains a namespace, even for the default namespace ([Modifying .config File in an MSBuild Project](http://yentran.org/blog/2012/05/11/modifying-config-file-in-an-msbuild-project/)).

However, I couldn't find any documentation for the `XmlPoke.Namespaces` parameter and the above referenced code didn't work.  After much trial an error, I finally got it to work with this:

```
<Target 
    Name="UpdateVSIXVersion" 
    BeforeTargets="PrepareForBuild" 
    Condition="$(VSIXVersion) != '' And $(VSIXVersion) != '*Undefined*'">

    <Message Text= "Updating VSIX Version" />

    <XmlPoke 
        XmlInputPath="source.extension.vsixmanifest"
        Query="/n:PackageManifest/n:Metadata/n:Identity/@Version"
        Value="$(VSIXVersion)"
        Namespaces="&lt;Namespace Prefix='n' Uri='http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/vsx-schema/2011' Name='DoNotKnowWhatThisIsFor-ButItIsRequired' /&gt;">
    </XmlPoke>
```

**Notes:**

- This requires MSBuild 12 to be configured on Team City
- The Namespaces needs to be escaped.
- The Name parameter is required, otherwise MSBuild will error out
- The original XPath query had to be updated with the artificial namespace prefix.

MSBuild file is on Github if anyone needs it: https://github.com/ppittle/pMixins/blob/master/tools/vssdk_tools/v12.0/VSSDK/Microsoft.VsSDK.targets